# How can I write a function in Selenium and call it from another page?

Tags: function, selenium

I'm new to Selenium. I need to write a function in Selenium. This is a sample code. If it is correct, where we will save this file and what is the extension? How can I call this function from another page?

Please help me.

Can you give me sample code for a function in Selenium?

```
package com.example.tests;

public void chk_test(String news){
   System.out.println("Success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, use an IDE, such as Eclipse.
Within the same project, you should be able to create different packages, and `import com.example.tests;` within a class to use your function as `chk_test(aString);`

Hope this helps get you started. There are tons of [articles](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#java)/tutorials to get setup with Selenium RC using Eclipse, programming in Java.